# Visualization of Gaussian undirected graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph

can someone help me with the visualization of the Gaussian undirected graph based on huge() function output? I prefer the **igraph** library or **ggplot2** library (*if possible*).

In addition, is there some rules how to setup the arguments within huge() function such as **lambda.min.ratio**, **nlambda** and **lambda**.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
library(huge)
set.seed(12345)
mat <- matrix(c( 1.000, -0.075, 0.123, -0.792, -0.223, -0.364, -0.299, -0.561, -0.469, -0.209,
                -0.075,  1.000, 0.002, -0.038, -0.074, -0.176, -0.064, -0.001, -0.100,  0.189,
                 0.123,  0.002, 1.000,  0.052,  0.093,  0.083,  0.144,  0.056,  0.069,  0.082,
                -0.792, -0.038, 0.052,  1.000,  0.140,  0.589,  0.434,  0.737,  0.636,  0.156,
                -0.223, -0.074, 0.093,  0.140,  1.000,  0.008,  0.049,  0.160,  0.101,  0.102,
                -0.364, -0.176, 0.083,  0.589,  0.008,  1.000,  0.559,  0.511,  0.743, -0.186,
                -0.299, -0.064, 0.144,  0.434,  0.049,  0.559,  1.000,  0.510,  0.417,  0.505,
                -0.561, -0.001, 0.056,  0.737,  0.160,  0.511,  0.510,  1.000,  0.698,  0.327,
                -0.469, -0.100, 0.069,  0.636,  0.101,  0.743,  0.417,  0.698,  1.000,  0.016,
                -0.209,  0.189, 0.082,  0.156,  0.102, -0.186,  0.505,  0.327,  0.016,  1.000),
                nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
rownames(mat) <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10")
colnames(mat) <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10")

m1 <- huge(mat,
           method = "glasso")
m1$lambda
m1$sparsity
m1$loglik
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something similar to this?

```
library(huge)
library(igraph)
set.seed(12345)
mat <- matrix(c( 1.000, -0.075, 0.123, -0.792, -0.223, -0.364, -0.299, -0.561, -0.469, -0.209,
                 -0.075,  1.000, 0.002, -0.038, -0.074, -0.176, -0.064, -0.001, -0.100,  0.189,
                 0.123,  0.002, 1.000,  0.052,  0.093,  0.083,  0.144,  0.056,  0.069,  0.082,
                 -0.792, -0.038, 0.052,  1.000,  0.140,  0.589,  0.434,  0.737,  0.636,  0.156,
                 -0.223, -0.074, 0.093,  0.140,  1.000,  0.008,  0.049,  0.160,  0.101,  0.102,
                 -0.364, -0.176, 0.083,  0.589,  0.008,  1.000,  0.559,  0.511,  0.743, -0.186,
                 -0.299, -0.064, 0.144,  0.434,  0.049,  0.559,  1.000,  0.510,  0.417,  0.505,
                 -0.561, -0.001, 0.056,  0.737,  0.160,  0.511,  0.510,  1.000,  0.698,  0.327,
                 -0.469, -0.100, 0.069,  0.636,  0.101,  0.743,  0.417,  0.698,  1.000,  0.016,
                 -0.209,  0.189, 0.082,  0.156,  0.102, -0.186,  0.505,  0.327,  0.016,  1.000),
              nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

m1 <- huge(mat, method = "glasso")

pathres <- m1$path[[9]]
rownames(pathres) <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10")
colnames(pathres) <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10")

g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(pathres, mode = "undirected")
plot(g)
```

Results in:
[image]

Regarding the selection of arguments and graph selection please refer to
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/huge/huge.pdf

Comment: Thanks!!! Still one question more. Why you taken ninth zero-one matrix from the output (m1$path[[9]])?

Comment: Great, please be so kind and accept the answer if it was useful.

I just took one of the 10 adjacency matrices of m1 to plot it via iGraph. I am not knowledgeable enough on the topic of model selection for Gaussian undirected graphs. That's why I linked the documentation of the package. I guess especially the section huge.select() might be interesting.